# Fatal error when starting RStudio

Tags: r, windows-8.1, rstudio

I'm new to R programming and got some trouble when installing RStudio.

Specs are:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- R x64 3.12
- Rstudio 0.98.1091

Message:

```
> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\毅\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKWJ7PZ\file23e853f05213': No such file or directory
Error installing package: Error in tools:::.install_packages() : cannot create temporary directory
```

I've tried reinstalling and restarted and Googled a lot but still can't figured it out.
My guess is that this may have something to do with my Chinese username 毅, but you can't change your username in Windows (I found some dirty ways to do it but can't afford the results).

Comment: Probably you should not change, but create new user with new username?

Comment: I reinstalled the system and everything works fine now...